# C++ Coding Issue

Tags: c++

I am getting this error as I am trying to compile my code. I am trying to make a simple calculator and I am having some trouble removing this final error. Any and all help is appreciated. 
The error I am getting is as follows   expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int intevaluate(int Left, char Operation, int Right);
void Intro();

int intLeft;
int intRight;
char charOperation;
int intAddition;
int intSubtraction;
int intMultiplication;
int intDivision;


void Intro()
{
cout << "These are the arithmetic operations you can choose to enter ";
cout << " + for addition\n - for subtraction\n * for multiplication\n and / for division\n";
}

intevaluate(intLeft, charOperation, intRight)
{
intAddition = intLeft + intRight;
intSubtraction = intLeft - intRight;
intMultiplication = intLeft * intRight;
intDivision = intLeft / intRight;


if (charOperation == "+")
{
cout << "The answer is " << intAddition;
}

else if (charOperation == "-")
{
cout << "The answer is " << intSubtraction; 
}

else if (charOperation == "*")  
{ 
cout << "The answer is " << intMultiplication;
}

else if (charOperation == "/") && ( Left || Right != 0)
{
cout << "The answer is " << intDivision;
}

else if (charOperation == "/") && ( Left || Right == 0)
{
cout << "You cannot divide by zero ";
}

}









int main()
{
cout << "Please enter an integer value and press enter: ";
cin >> intLeft;

cout << "\nPlease enter another integer value and press enter: ";
cin >> intRight;

Intro();

cout << "\nPlease enter an arithmetic operation from the list above and  press enter: ";
cin >> charOperation;


intevaluate(intLeft, charOperation, intRight);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have messed up the function argument names.

```
if (Operation == +)
{
    // ...
}
```

What is Operation? You pass the function a char with argument name

```
charOperation
```

not
    Operation

You can't compare characters like that. You must do

```
if(charOperation == '+')
```

and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I fixed the error you pointed out but I am still getting the same error message at the start of the intevaluate function

Comment: What is the error output the compiler gives you? Does it give you a line number?

Comment: [Error] expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token Thats the error I get and line 30 it says , which is just after the void intro function

Comment: It's impossible for me to tell without more information. Edit your original post perhaps and post the "fixed" code (the alterations you made based on my first answer).

Comment: I saw that you wrote intLeft for example in your function definition, typo!

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the all the help

Comment: If it solved your problem then accept the answer so this thread can be closed. Your welcome!